# Could not connect to database server: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1835 Malformed communication packet

Tags: mariadb, whmcs

Hello recently started having this issue with WHMCS, All the DB credentials are working and i even setup a test script and it also shows as working with that. Does anyone know what this issue is?

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade your PHP version to at least 7.3.
Reference: https://help.whmcs.com/m/troubleshooting/l/1325182-troubleshooting-a-critical-error-could-not-connect-to-the-database-error